# When is a point satisfying $F_1(x_1, x_2) = A$ and $F_2(x_1, x_2) = B$ an isolated point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be two smooth functions defined over $\mathbb{R}^2$. 
Suppose  a point $(z_1, z_2)$ satisfies $F_1(z_1, z_2) = A$ and $F_2(z_1, z_2) = B$. I was wondering, under what conditions can I make sure that this point $(z_1, z_2)$ is an isolated point? (by which I mean that there exists a small open ball $U$ around $(z_1, z_2)$ such that this doesn't happen on $U$ except at $(z_1, z_2)$) Any comments are appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Saddle point or not ? That might be related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One sufficient (non-necessary) condition for the point being isolated is given by the inverse function theorem. Consider $$G:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2,\quad(z_1,z_2)\mapsto(F_1(z_1,z_2),F_2(z_1,z_2)).$$If we assume that the two gradients $\nabla F_1(z_1,z_2)$ and $\nabla F_2(z_1,z_2)$ are linearly independent, then the differential of $G$ at $(z_1,z_2)$ is non-singular, and so, the inverse function theorem guarantees a neighborhood $U$ on which $G$ is a diffeomorphism. In particular, $G$ is injective in $U$.

Comment: I see. Is that mean if I had $n$ functions from $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and want to generalize the statement to this setting, then it is sufficient that its Jacobian be a non-singular matrix at that point?

Comment: @JohnnyT. Yes, it does.